# Cannot edit update-manager-core even after having sudo permissions. Need it essentially in order to upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04.1 to 22.10!

Tags: upgrade, permissions, gnome-terminal, gedit, 22.10

`/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`
I have to upgrade **Ubuntu 22.04.1** to **22.10**. I'm following steps to do that from [this website](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-from-22-04-to-22-10). **Step-4** of the procedure to be followed asks to **edit** `update-manager-core` by **adding** `Prompt=normal`. This step can't be followed as **Terminal** is **denying me access** to do so (***Screenshot attached***).
**Please help me to bypass this situation and upgrade to 22.10...**[image: Permission Denied!]

Comment: You are following instructions that seem poorly written in spots. The actual instruction is to "*Open and edit the /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades file*," but it does not tell you how to do so.

Comment: Oh thank you for mentioning the error to me... @user535733

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

`sudo nano /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`

Explanation: you have to use some text editor in root mode.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a desktop OS, you don't have to edit anything manually.

You can go to Software & Updates application and choose to upgrade to a non-LTS Ubuntu version.

But for a very new user it is not recommended.

Comment: I've dual booted Ubuntu 22.04.1 with Windows 11. Well, I wanted to download ISO of Ubuntu 22.10, but by mistakenly I downloaded it of 22.04.1 and created a USB boot Drive of it. Now I just wanted to ask why it isn't recommended for new users?

Comment: Non-LTS versions have only 9 months support and usually are less stable. You'll have to upgrade every 6 months to new releases that may contain some new features not really tested very well. The upgrade process is not always straight forward. For a new user who doesn't have enough skills it is a real challenge.

Comment: If you want a system that will work for a long time without surprises, LTS is the right choice.